# Audio Playback Speed Manipulation in the Browser

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm not asking for hand-holding (yet) but I just wanted to know if it was possible to load an audio file in Javascript (Or Python, which seems like another server-side possibility) and be able to manipulate the playback speed, both slower and faster.  I'm just starting my research in this, and wondered if anyone else has messed with audio manipulation in the browser and what was the best platform to do that in (Javascript, Python, etc. seem like there might be a possibility for this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html

The web audio api allows you to do exactly that.